# Django ordering by a foreign key field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models as listed below:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.TexField()

class Item(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_item')
    name = models.TextField()
    available = models.FloatField()
```

So I need to fetch all Projects, however I want them such that, all those Projects which have Items that have `available` greater than `0`, should come first.

I tried this:

```
list = Projects.objects.filter(**Some Fields**).order_by(available)
```

How can I sort this list?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow relations in ordering clauses with double underscore like so:

```
list = Projects.objects.filter(**Some Fields**).order_by('-item__available')
```

This orders projects in descending order by related items' available field.

Comment: Please show your full, actual, model. It is clear that you are missing some attributes from the code you have posted, for example a ForeignKey requires an `on_delete` attribute; did you also miss out a `related_name`?

Comment: In that case you can sort with order_by('-project_item__available')

Comment: This has caused data replication, how can I add a distinct clause, actually I am new to Django, transitioning from Java.

Comment: @Paras just add distinct() to the end like this:  list = Projects.objects.filter(**Some Fields**).order_by('-item__available').distinct()

Comment: `distinct()` is no use here as the rows returned by the SQL query are not technically duplicates as they include the unique related fields used for ordering. See the [note under `distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) in the Django docs.

Comment: So how shall I remove the duplicates?